# Sharing HP LaserJet 1300 from Windows 7 to Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printer, network-printer

I'm having trouble sharing an HP LaserJet 1300 series printer, installed on Windows 7, with a computer running Windows XP on the local network (or vice-versa). The problem seems to be related to the additional printer drivers Windows exposes to remote computers.

Could there be anyone with some information about how I can install additional drivers for x64 processor of type3 -user mode?

My Windows7 computer has x86 type3-usermode driver already installed but the x64 is giving me problem and I understand I need to install it before I share the printer with a computer installed with windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sharing a printer from a x86 machine to x64 machines you have to package the correct x64 driver for the printer on the machine hosting the printer.

Go to Printers
Right Click the Printer in Question
Printer Properties
Sharing Tab
Additional Drivers

Then browse for the x64 versions of the drivers.

Hope this helps.